# Read files from BOOT-INF/classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with a java resource folder:

```
src
 |
  main
   |
    resources
     |
      test
       |
        test1.json
        test2.json
        ...
```

In the resource folder there are json files. I can read these files within my IDE (IntelliJ). But as a compiled JAR file, I get `Nullpointer` exceptions.

Spring Boot copies the files to: `BOOT-INF/classes/test` Is it possible to read the resource files within a JAR file? I don't know the file names. So in first, I have to get all file names and the read each file.

Does anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE**

I have tried this:

```
Resources[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:**/test/*.json");
```

With that I'm getting all file paths. But that needs too much time. And even if I get the file names, how would I read the files?

Comment: Have you tried with ResourceLoader ?

Comment: If those are test files, I'd say they belong under src/test/resources, not src/main/resources.  If not, I'd put them under src/main/resources and give them more sensible names.  Load resources from classpath:test/test1.json and classpath:test/test2.json.

Comment: @duffymo I named it like that just for posting the question here. In real the files have other names. And as I said, I don't know the names of the files to call them directly. I'm only knowing the folder name.

Comment: One at a time would be my recommendation.  "classpath:test/test1.json" and "classpath:test/test2.json".

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know the file name!

Comment: @CPA You don't know the file names but if you know the folder they would be in then you might reduce your search time by restricting a little bit your file name expression to Resources[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:test/*.json"); Can you try that?

Comment: @artemisian: Then Spring doesn't find the files :/

Comment: Can you try Resources[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:BOOT-INF/classes/test/*.json");

Comment: @artemisian Sorry, your first approach is working. There was a mistake on my site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below solution will read the files into a Map.

Here you read your resources:

```
Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:test/*.json"); 
for (Resource r: resources) {
     processResource(r);
}
```

Here you process your resources:

```
// you need to add a dependency (if you don't have it already) for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

private void processResource(Resource resource) {
    try {
          Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Map.class);

          // do stuffs with your jsoMap

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to my first comment, it is also working without "BOOT-INF/classes‌​" in classpath.

Answer (score 10):

This actually works using a ResourcePatternResolver

```java
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:test/*.json");

    for(Resource r: resources) {
        InputStream inputStream = r.getInputStream();
        File somethingFile = File.createTempFile(r.getFilename(), ".cxl");
        try {
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, somethingFile);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }
        LicenseManager.setLicenseFile(somethingFile.getAbsolutePath());
        log.info("File Path is " + somethingFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are doing in your answer and why it is reasonable.