# JavaCompiler API in a Spring Boot app and get classpath

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-compiler-api

I'm using JavaCompiler API in Spring boot application. But currently I'm facing with an issue on getting spring boot runnable jar file classpath using System.getProperty("java.class.path") it is returning only path to this jar...

Is there any way to get real classpath with all jar files in springbootapp.jar/BOOT-INF/lib ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read files from BOOT-INF/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655397/read-files-from-boot-inf-classes)

Comment: @EdwinCarlsson no, it doesn't work for jar files